# Почему не получается переопределить background-color

Tags: css, вёрстка, frontend, scss, sass

В зависимости от состояния, блок должен менять цвет. Все нечетные блоки имеют цвет `$smoky-white`, а блоки в состоянии `open` должны иметь цвет `$platinum`.

Проблема в то, что у `&:nth-child(odd)` блоков цвет в состоянии `open` не переопределяет цвет `&:nth-child(odd)`, в DevTools браузера цвет от `open` зачеркнут, хотя специфичность у селектора класса и всевдокласса одинаковая. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

JSX:

```
function ListRecord({ record, key }: IListRecordProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div
      key={key}
      onClick={() => setOpen((value) => !value)}
      className={classNames(styles.record, open && styles.record_open)}
    >
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

SCSS:

```
    .record {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      column-gap: 15px;
      row-gap: 12px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 20px 16px;

      &:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: $smoky-white;
      }

      &_open {
        background-color: $platinum;
      }  
    }
```

Comment: Наверное, потому что класс имеет бОльший вес, чем селектор... Например, http://css.yoksel.ru/specifity/

Comment: Так же нужно помнить что при "равности" селекторов, приоритетнее будет тот, что расположен "ниже"  в каскадном списке селекторов...

Comment: &_open ниже расположен